# How do I make an IF ELSE while using WITH END WITH statement?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, with-statement

How do I insert an If Else Statement here when I want to display the studentID and loginID if there is no student name/address.

```
Sub ShowStudentInfo()
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetInfoForStudent("test", frmLogin.txtusername.Text, frmLogin.txtPassword.Text)

    With dt.Rows(0)
        frmLibrary.txtStudentID.Text = .Item("StudentID")
        frmLibrary.txtLoginID.Text = .Item("LoginID")
        frmLibrary.txtStudentName.Text = .Item("Student Name")
        frmLibrary.txtStudentAddress.Text = .Item("Student address")


    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub ShowStudentInfo()
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetInfoForStudent("test", frmLogin.txtusername.Text, frmLogin.txtPassword.Text)

    With dt.Rows(0)
        if .Item("Student Name")="" and .Item("Student address")="" then
            frmLibrary.txtStudentID.Text = .Item("StudentID")
            frmLibrary.txtLoginID.Text = .Item("LoginID")
        else
            frmLibrary.txtStudentName.Text = .Item("Student Name")
            frmLibrary.txtStudentAddress.Text = .Item("Student address")
        end if

    End With
End Sub
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yea something like that but If I login with a user that doesn't have a Student Name/Address it will give me this error  
There is no row at position 0.

Comment: Should use the String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace  --  if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(.item("Student Name")) andAlso String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(.item("Student Address")) then

Comment: where do I place the String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace??

Comment: It states that 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' is not a member of a 'String'

Comment: Just as I mentioned above. In the "If" line you put String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace around each .Item("blahblah"). You should also use AndAlso instead of And. This short-circuits the If statement, so that if the first part is false, then it doesn't even bother checking the second part. AND works fine in most situations, but AndAlso would be a small savings in performance.

Comment: IsNUllOrWhiteSpace is used in .NET 4.0. If earlier version of .NET, then IsNullOrEmpty should work in most situations.

Comment: it still doesn't display anything

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With dt.Rows(0)
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(.Item("Student Name")) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(.Item("Student Address")) Then
                    frmLibrary.txtStudentID.Text = .Item("StudentID")
                    frmLibrary.txtLoginID.Text = .Item("LoginID")
                Else
                    frmLibrary.txtStudentName.Text = .Item("Student Name")
                    frmLibrary.txtStudentAddress.Text = .Item("Student address")
                End If
            End With
        End If

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7395/discussion-between-completenewb-and-aprough)

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Gage's answer.  You are getting no results because your GetInfoForStudent function is not returning a row.  When this happens, your If statement on the Row Count has no Else clause.  Put some code there to add a row or whatever, and it should work out.

```
Sub ShowStudentInfo()     
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetInfoForStudent("test", frmLogin.txtusername.Text, frmLogin.txtPassword.Text)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0  then    
        With dt.Rows(0)         
            if String.IsNullOrEmpty(.Item("Student Name")) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(.Item("Student Name")) then                     
                frmLibrary.txtStudentID.Text = .Item("StudentID")             
                frmLibrary.txtLoginID.Text = .Item("LoginID")         
            else             
                frmLibrary.txtStudentName.Text = .Item("Student Name")                             
                frmLibrary.txtStudentAddress.Text = .Item("Student address")         
            end if      
        End With    
    Else
        'Do something here to add new row, etc.
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Sorry just came back from lunch and checked this. This seems to be the correct answer so theres no need for me to amend mine.

Comment: @Gage.  Sorry, didn't mean to step on your toes.

Comment: No not at all. You took the initiative yourself which is a good thing. There was no way to know if or when I would check this again. Dont worry about it.